# how to convert css style syntax in haml

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, haml

I got the wrong haml in  http://html2haml.heroku.com/

How to convert it in proper way ?

Because the haml didn't render the identical html when I load the page

### HTML

```
<style media="screen">
      img { display: none; }
            body { overflow: hidden; }
            #canvas { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
</style>
```

### HAML by http://html2haml.heroku.com/

```
%style{media: "screen"}
  :cdata
    img { display: none; }
    body { overflow: hidden; }
    \#canvas { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
```

Comment: Why are you using inline styles? Move them to assets

Comment: Using inline is handy to test something works without having to recompile assets; if it works, then can move it to assets

Comment: For the sake of motivation, email layouts require inline stylesheets.

Answer (score 13):

This should work

```
%body
  :css
    img { display: none; }
    body { overflow: hidden; }
    #canvas { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
```

P.S. But this's a bad practice to render html content which should be located in separate file.

Comment: This won’t include the `media="screen"` attribute. You’ll need to use an actual tag (e.g. `%style(media="screen")`) in order to get the attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try [**htmltohaml**](http://htmltohaml.com/)

Input:

```
<style media="screen">
      img { display: none; }
      body { overflow: hidden; }
      #canvas { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
</style>
```

Output:

```
%style{:media => "screen"}
  img { display: none; }
  body { overflow: hidden; }
  \#canvas { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
```

Anyways, as Mandeep [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25102308/how-to-convert-css-style-syntax-in-haml/25102336?noredirect=1#comment39062531_25102308), I also recommend that **you should move your styles to stylesheets**.

Comment: It's a bad practice to use inline styles

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you, in case you don't want CDATA tokens in your code.

```
%style{media: "screen"}
  :plain
    img { display: none; }
    body { overflow: hidden; }
    #canvas { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
```